# Построение параллелепипедов и кубов по координатам вершин

Tags: python, алгоритм, unity3d, matplotlib, графика

Есть n-ое количество трехмерных фигур - параллелепипедов и кубов (вплоть до 20 млн), представленных координатами вершин. Как я могу получить такой результат, желательно с возможностью задания разных цветов для кубов? В примере "кубом" для удобства я назвал параллелепипеды
[image: построение происходит соответственно от куба 1 к кубу 6]

Координаты вершин для куба из примера:

```
cube1 = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1],
         [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, -1], [1, 1, -1]]

cube2 = [[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -1],
        [1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [1, 1, -1], [2, 1, -1]]

cube3 = [[2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [2, 0, -1], [3, 0, -1],
        [2, 1, 0], [3, 1, 0], [2, 1, -1], [3, 1, -1]]

cube4 = [[0, 0, -1], [1, 0, -1], [0, 0, -2], [1, 0, -2],
        [0, 1, -1], [1, 1, -1], [0, 1, -2], [1, 1, -2]]

cube5 = [[1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -1], [1, 0, -2], [2, 0, -2],
         [1, 1, -1], [2, 1, -1], [1, 1, -2], [2, 1, -2]]

cube6 = [[2, 0, -1], [3, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [3, 0, -2],
        [2, 1, -1], [3, 1, -1], [2, 1, -2], [3, 1, -2]]
```

Comment: генерировать кубы по координатам в даном случае, как мне кажется, это бессмысленно. Посчитай размеры куба, создай один единственный куб и размести его со всеми необходимыми сдвигами. А сдвиги будут размером с renderer.bounds. Так же никаких проблем не возникнет с ассайном материала и заданием цвета кубу - на готовый обьект это чисто выбрать цвет у шейдера с возможностью изменения цвета.

Comment: @Yaroslav Возможно Вы, как человек, понимающий суть проблемы, можете посоветовать инструмент для её решения или метод?

Comment: @Andrew, спасибо. Скажите, пожалуйста, как это можно осуществить?

Answer (score 0):

ответ без кода.

1. Создаешь скрипт
2. в старт или эвейк запускаешь метод GenerateCubes() который принимает количество повторений кубов по координатам x, y, z
3. сам метод берет готовый префаб с кубом с наперед назначенным шейдером (у которого можно менять цвет через рендерер)
4. генеришь поле из кубов с неоюходимыми смещением. Размеры куба берутся по renderer.bounds. Циклом. Каждая следующая позиция будет  renderer.bounds.x * i.
5. Если нужно в высоту еще - то делаешь вложенный цикл и смещение у нового обьекта нужно будет делать на renderer.bounds.y * j.
6. то же самое с глубиной если необходимо. Для всех циклов использовать входные данные в GenerateCubes

создавать обьект с префаба можно по instantiate

это если в двух словах. Это более чем детальные указания,  код писать не буду. Он реально детский. Не сможешь разобраться по этим указаниям, лучше пойти разбираться с чем-то другим и вернутся в программирование через годик тренировки на консольных программах.

Comment: Спасибо, по коду и подходу нет вопросов, здесь всё кристально понятно. Я скорее всего, неправильно выразился изначально, чем я могу это визуализировать? Я и написал-то matplotlib и unity потому что не нашёл инструмента где через ооп можно это построить. Pygame?

Comment: любой 3д редактор + родные скрипты редактора. Это если нужен рендер или просто 3д модель. Если нужно взаимодействие - юнити. Я лично отвечал по направлению юнити и на другие тэги не смотрел